# Is there any way to set the points of a freeform light in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

I'm trying to recreate family fortunes (Feud in America) and I'm trying to make a spotlight that follows the mouse. The code for the spot to follow the mouse works fine but I'm having trouble changing the freeform light which is supposed to be the beam leading up to the spot. I found some code in the Unity documentation so i know its possible but i just can't get it to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Spot;
    public GameObject Beam;

    public Vector3 screenPos;
    public Vector3 worldPos;

    public void SetShapePath(Vector2[] path)
    {
        new Vector2(-10, 0);
        new Vector2(Spot.transform.position.x - 1, Spot.transform.position.y);
        new Vector2(Spot.transform.position.x + 1, Spot.transform.position.y);

        SetShapePath(path);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        screenPos = Input.mousePosition;

        worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos);
        
        Spot.transform.position = new Vector3(worldPos.x, worldPos.y, worldPos.z + 10);

    }
}
```

The unity console is returning no errors so I struggle to see why it's not working, I'm assuming it's to do with I haven't assigned the Vector2's properly or the freeform light isn't using them. Some help would be appreciated, ideally before mid-December, thanks.

P.S The finished game will be uploaded to Itch when it's done.

Comment: Inside `SetShapePath` you are creating few `Vector2` but you do not assign them to anything. They are just created and lost. Plus that method is infinitely calling back itself.

Comment: You call `SetShapePath(path);` .. from within `SetShapePath(Vector2[] path);` .. are you sure there is no errors because this would pretty much throw a StackOverflow ;) => Is `SetShapePath` being called at all? And as already mentioned right now it doesn't actually do anything (apart from crash) ...

Comment: @Nikaas I decently fairly new to Unity and C# and I don't actually know how Arrays work. How do I assign them to the freeform light? Should I put the ```SetShapePath(path)``` somewhere else?

Comment: @derHugo No there are definitely no errors and it doesn't crash, it just does nothing. How do I check if ```SetShapePath``` is being called?

Comment: @code_bean193935 If I were in your shoes I would leave Unity alone for a month and do just pure C# tutorials. Having to simultaneously figure out Unity and C# is too much new info to make sense of. Most people that try both get overwhelmed and give up.

Comment: @code_bean193935 add debug logs or use breakpoints - see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html

Comment: By “fairly new” I meant about a year. @Nikaas I need to be done in a month. I’m not struggling to understand both I just can’t find anything on how to create/edit arrays.

Comment: Those 2 link can help you with arrays - https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_arrays.php  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/arrays